# full text search android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a problem with a full text search. when i search it's just search the first word 
for example i have "Project Test" i can find it just with searching Project but when i try searching "Test" i can't find it please tell me how to do i give you my code

```
public static Cursor fetchProjectCursor(String name)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    Cursor cursor = DataBaseUtil.dataBaseAccess().query(
            _PROJECT_TABLE,
            _FIELD_NAME,
         "(" + _NAME + ")" + " LIKE " +  "(" + "\""
                + name + "%" + "\"" + ")", null, null, null, _MODIFIED_DATE);

    return cursor;
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add **"%"** before name .

```
Cursor cursor = DataBaseUtil.dataBaseAccess().query(
            _PROJECT_TABLE,
            _FIELD_NAME,
         "(" + _NAME + ")" + " LIKE " +  "(" + "\"" + "%"
                + name + "%" + "\"" + ")", null, null, null, _MODIFIED_DATE);
```

### Or

Try this.

```
return db.rawQuery("select * from your_table_name where column_name like ?", new String[] {"%"+name+"%"});
```

It return Cursor.

Comment: i tride this  return DataBaseUtil.dataBaseAccess().rawQuery("select * from _PROJECT_TABLE where _NAME like ?", new String[] {"%"+name+"%"});
 }

Comment: but not working logcat told me no such table : _PROJECT_TABLE and my table is like that public static final String _CREATE_PROJECT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
   + _PROJECT_TABLE
   + " ("
   + _ID
   + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
   + _PROJECT_ID
   + " LONG NOT NULL,"
   + _GROUP_ID
   + " LONG NULL,"
   + _COMPANY_ID
   + " LONG NULL,"
   + _USER_ID
   + " LONG NULL,"
   + _USER_UUID
   + " LONG NULL,"
   + _CREATE_DATE
   + " VARCHAR(50) NULL,"
   + _MODIFIED_DATE
   + " VARCHAR(50) NULL,"

Comment: You need to put  _PROJECT_TABLE value instead of your_table_name and _NAME value instead of column_name .

Comment: i'm new in the website i don't know how to use it sorrry

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an '%' before the name parameter like the following:

```
public static Cursor fetchProjectCursor(String name)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    Cursor cursor = DataBaseUtil.dataBaseAccess().query(
            _PROJECT_TABLE,
            _FIELD_NAME,
         "(" + _NAME + ")" + " LIKE " +  "(" + "\"" + "%"
                + name + "%" + "\"" + ")", null, null, null, _MODIFIED_DATE);

    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at build in Full text support in SQLite.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE mytable USING fts3 (text TEXT);
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE text MATCH "text to match";
```

Inside fts3 virtual table all tables are in TEXT even if you declare INTEGER. So you may find helpful to split table into two tables. It needs a litle bit work, but splitting can be done on databese layer. But result will be better. With a more rows and larger lines you can see a big speed improvement.